# Integral inequality problem

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)\in(0,1)$ for every $x\in(0,1).$  Show that
$$\left(\int_0^1f(x)dx\right)^2>\int_0^1(f(x))^3dx$$
I am not even sure how to begin to solve this problem.  Any help/hints is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: http://books.google.ro/books?id=ge6nk9W0BCcC&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=cauchy-+bunyakovsky+-schwarz+integral+inequality&source=bl&ots=bdhhMb0tcS&sig=oXvRN2RPZ1uTprB6yr5dNwa6mxg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IiE7U6PeD62M7Abaj4CAAg&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=cauchy-%20bunyakovsky%20-schwarz%20integral%20inequality&f=false I think this can help you. I am very curious to find out a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I am still working on it and if I come up with something I will post it as an answer to see if someone can check to see it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote 
$$
F(t)=\left(\int_0^tf(x)dx\right)^2-\int_0^t(f(x))^3dx, t\in[0,1]
$$
Then we have
$$
F'(t)=f(t)\left(2\int_0^tf(x)dx-(f(t))^2\right)
$$
and if $G(t)=2\int_0^tf(x)dx-(f(t))^2$ then $G'(t)=2f(t)(1-f'(t))\ge 0$.

Then, $G(t)\ge G(0)=0$ giving $F'(t)\ge 0$. Thus $F(t)\ge 0$, in particular $F(1)\ge 0$.

Comment: Should the upper limit in the second integral in the first line be $t$?

Comment: @JasonZimba Good eyes, thanks.